# v-select binding values to objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a v-select that maps objects this way:

```
<v-select
      v-model="object"
      :items="objectsArray"
      label="Select Object"          
      item-text="name"
      item-value="id"
></v-select>
```

Where:

- object have this structure: {'id': 'Foo','name':'Bar'}
- And ObjectsArray is an array of objects with the same structure {'id': 'Foo','name':'Bar'}

Here is the thing: When initial render happens works fine displaying the name property in the select, but when change object becomes a string with the 'name' of the selected Item i.e. 'Bar' .

Questions: 
1-How can object be replaced with the full value of selected items i.e: {'id':'Foo','name':'Bar'}  instead of the item-text property only.
2-How can object be replaced with id property only i.e.'Foo'.

Observation:
If removes `item-text` form `v-select`. Shows `[Object object]` on the select BUT on change updates object with the item-value property in this case the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.

```html
<v-select
      v-model="object"
      :items="objectsArray"
      label="Select Object"          
      item-text="name"
      item-value="id"
      return-object
></v-select>
```

2. `v-model` always reflects value of property defined in `item-value`, not the `item-text`. So in your example select will show `Bar` and `v-model` will have the value of `Foo`

Comment: Right in both cases. Thanks.